# Using converters in Pandas read_hdf similar to read_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, hdf

In pandas `read_csv` there is a kwarg `converters` which allows you to define a dictionary of columns and conversions to implement on them. For example say I have a csv with some columns that contain arrays. Simply reading this csv will load the DataFrame with these columns as strings. You can either use `df.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x.col_name))` or when loading the csv enter `pd.read_csv(filename, connverters={'col_name': ast.literal_eval})`.

I noticed that in the documentation for [`read_hdf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.read_hdf.html) there is a `where` kwarg that states: *list of Term (or convertable) objects, optional*. This makes me feel like I could use converters when loading from a hdf file in a similar way. Unfortunately I cannot find any examples of this. Is this a possibility or have I interpreted the documentation incorrectly?

Comment: `where` is for selecting a subset, like in SQL. Look at the docs for an [example](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/io.html#id2).

Comment: I have. Just was thrown of by the line **list of Term (or convertable) objects** as it made it seem like i could throw in a conversion as well.